# #ifnotdef : Error " multiple definition of 'member function' "

Tags: c++

can anyone tell me why am I getting a

```
 " multiple definition of 'member function' "
```

error , even though i've used the #ifnotdef statements in the class headers

Comment: `#ifnotdef` ? i don't think that's something that works. try `#ifndef`

Comment: but when i merge the two files the error is removed...:/

Comment: actually i'm using eclipse so these tags are automatically added, and all the other classes are working perfectly fine with these tags...:P

Comment: bdw it was a typo...it actually is #ifndef in the classes...:P

Answer (score 3):

That `#ifnotdef` does not work. The correct precompiler switch is `#ifndef` or `#if !defined()`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the header is included in more than one module and contains the function definition . As for #ifnotdef then I think it is a typo is not it? Otherwise the compiler would issue an other error.

Comment: yes it was a typo...:P

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that the headers contain include guards:

```
#ifndef SOME_HEADER_H  // not #ifnotdef
#define SOME_HEADER_H

// header contents

#endif
```

this will only prevent multiple inclusion in a single translation unit. It will *not* prevent anything defined in there from being multiply defined, if you include it in multiple translation units.

To fix the problem, the definitions of any functions declared in the header can be either:

- moved into a source file, so there is only one definition; or
- made `inline`, so that multiple definitions are allowed; or
- if they're member functions, moved into the class definition, so that they're implicitly inline.